# Как сделать, чтобы до 1000px отображался, как для мобильного экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Добрый вечер, столкнулся с проблемой. Хотел сделать, чтобы до 1000px страницу отображало, как для мобильного экрана, но возникла проблема пропадает `slide-menu` при разрешении от 768px до 1000px.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main-nav.navbar .container-fluid').append($('<div id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));
  var toggler = '.navbar-toggle';
  var pagewrapper = '#page-content';
  var navigationwrapper = '.navbar-header';
  var menuwidth = '100%';
  var slidewidth = '80%';
  var menuneg = '-100%';
  var slideneg = '-80%';
  $("#main-nav").on("click", toggler, function(e) {
    var selected = $(this).hasClass('slide-active');
    $('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
      left: selected ? menuneg : '0px'
    });
    $('#navbar-height-col').stop().animate({
      left: selected ? slideneg : '0px'
    });
    $(pagewrapper).stop().animate({
      left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
    });
    $(navigationwrapper).stop().animate({
      left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('slide-active', !selected);
    $('#slidemenu').toggleClass('slide-active');
    $('#page-content, .navbar, body, .navbar-header').toggleClass('slide-active');
  });
  var selected = '#slidemenu, #page-content, body, .navbar, .navbar-header';
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 767 && $('.navbar-toggle').is(':hidden')) {
      $(selected).removeClass('slide-active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body.slide-active {
  overflow-x: hidden
}

.no-margin-top {
  margin-top: 0px!important
}

#page-content {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 70px;
  left: 0;
}

#page-content.slide-active {
  padding-top: 0
}

#main-nav .navbar-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

#main-nav .navbar-toggle>.icon-bar {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#main-nav .navbar-toggle.slide-active .icon-bar {
  background: #f8c957;
}

.navbar-header {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
  position: relative;
}

#login-dp {
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 14px 14px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

#login-dp .help-block {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#login-dp .bottom {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  clear: both;
  padding: 14px;
}

#login-dp .social-buttons {
  margin: 12px 0;
}

#login-dp .social-buttons a {
  width: 49%;
}

#login-dp .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar-static-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-nav #login-dp {
    background-color: inherit;
    color: gray;
  }
  .navbar-nav #login-dp .col-md-12 {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 0;
    min-width: 100px;
  }
  #login-dp .form {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #login-dp .bottom {
    background-color: inherit;
    border-top: 0 none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 0;
    min-width: 100px;
  }
  #slidemenu .navbar-right {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  #slidemenu .nabvbar-menu {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-toggle .caret {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown>a {
    outline: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    color: gray;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a,
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    background-image: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: gray;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: gray;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: gray;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: gray;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .divider {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  #main-nav .container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0!important;
  }
  #main-nav .navbar-header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  #main-nav .navbar.slide-active {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    top: -1px;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  #main-nav #slidemenu {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    left: -100%;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -8px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #main-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #main-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 80%;
    white-space: normal;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
  }
  #main-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: gray;
  }
  #main-nav {
    border-top: 0
  }
  #main-nav #navbar-height-col {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    left: -80%;
    background: #f8f8f8;
  }
  #main-nav .navbar-form {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8px 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*fast clearfixer*/
  }
  #main-nav .navbar-form .form-control {
    text-align: center
  }
  #main-nav .navbar-form .btn {
    width: 100%
  }
  .side-collapse.in {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  #page-content {
    left: 0!important
  }
  .navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
    position: fixed
  }
  .navbar-header {
    left: 0!important
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="color: gray;">Product-name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="slidemenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Личный кабинет</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#">Something there</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something there</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something there</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something there</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something there</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something there</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nabvbar-menu">
        <li><a href="http://est5.ru/tsentr-krasoty-i-zdorovya/vzroslye.html" target="_blank">Something there</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://est5.ru/klinika-stomatologii-i-implantologii/vzroslye.html" target="_blank">Something there</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://est5.ru/detskij-tsentr-razvitiya-i-tvorchestva.html" target="_blank">Something there</a></li>
        <li><a href=" http://est5.ru/tsentr-samorazvitiya-i-samopoznaniya/joga.html" target="_blank">Something there</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://est-shop.ru/" target="_blank">Something there</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s47vjcqs/2/

Comment: Зачем нужно вот это `$(window).width() > 767` сравнение?

Comment: @diraria удалить класс `slide-active` который появляется. когда шторка `slide-menu` выдвинута

Comment: Почему там `767`, а не, например, `999`?

Comment: @diraria потому что при 999 тоже не работает, как мне хотелось бы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы все правильно работало и ничего не ломалось, тебе нужно скачать sass исходники bootstrap и переопределить переменные в `_variables.scss` для `xs`, `sm`, `md` устройств.

Ну и в js у тебя условие, не `>767`, а `>1000` получается